# What is a use of adding a fragment code inside the activity layout file?

Tags: android

This is activity.java file and bellow is related xml layout file

```
package com.example.android.quakereport;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity);
    }

    public static class EarthquakePreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    }
}
```

what is the use of adding this fragment code inside the activity layout file

```
<fragment
    android:name="com.example.android.quakereport.SettingsActivity$EarthquakePreferenceFragment"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.quakereport.SettingsActivity">
</fragment>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fragment will hold the reference of some fragment which can be replaced by another fragment if needed.

Comment: Kindly upvote the answer if it worked for you. It will help others too.